# TSQL - Invalid column name that is present

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not the world's greatest SQL author, but up until now I thought I was at least decent at this.  I am trying to write a query that sums the count of a column based on input parameters and find this some where a date falls between a start date and an end date.

However, I cannot make reference to the date column, even though the column exists in one of the tables I'm querying.  I get back an error from SQL Server Studio that says "Invalid column name".  Note that this column name is unique between the two tables and I'm using the qualified name, so the chances of a naming conflict are low in my opinion.  Below is the SQL I'm using:

```
USE [DB_RPE_CONFIG]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @DOCTYPE INT

-- Leave unset to select all form type
-- SET @DOCTYPE = 700000
SET @STARTDATE = CONVERT(datetime, '2016-06-08 00:00:00')
SET @ENDDATE   = CONVERT(datetime, '2016-06-10 23:59:59')

SELECT r_sdf_definition.code,
       Sum("Forms Filed with Payment")    AS "Forms Filed with Payment", 
       Sum("Forms Filed without Payment") AS "Forms Filed without Payment"
FROM   (SELECT sdf_definition_key,
               Count(*) AS "Forms Filed with Payment", 
               0        AS "Forms Filed without Payment" 
        FROM   its_extnl_staging_document 
        WHERE  sdf_definition_key = Isnull(@DOCTYPE, sdf_definition_key) 
               AND remittance_amount > 0 
        GROUP  BY sdf_definition_key 
        UNION 
        SELECT sdf_definition_key, 
               0        AS "Forms Filed with Payment", 
               Count(*) AS "Forms Filed without Payment" 
        FROM   its_extnl_staging_document 
        WHERE  sdf_definition_key = Isnull(@DOCTYPE, sdf_definition_key) 
               AND remittance_amount = 0 
        GROUP  BY sdf_definition_key) its_extnl_staging_document 
       LEFT JOIN r_sdf_definition 
              ON its_extnl_staging_document.sdf_definition_key = 
                 r_sdf_definition.sdf_definition_key
       WHERE its_extnl_staging_document.submitted_dttm BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
GROUP  BY r_sdf_definition.code
```

When I attempt to use the query without the WHERE clause, the results come back fine.  I get the totals for the various form types, whether I specify the form type specifically or let it default to all the form types present.

Can anyone make any suggestions or point me in the right direction?

Edit --------------------

By taking the suggested course of adding the where specification to the inner selects, I get the following.  However the outer select still errors out the same way:

```
SELECT r_sdf_definition.code,
       Sum("Forms Filed with Payment")    AS "Forms Filed with Payment", 
       Sum("Forms Filed without Payment") AS "Forms Filed without Payment"
FROM   (SELECT sdf_definition_key,
               Count(*) AS "Forms Filed with Payment", 
               0        AS "Forms Filed without Payment", 
               "submitted_dttm" AS submitted_dttm
        FROM   its_extnl_staging_document 
        WHERE  sdf_definition_key = Isnull(@DOCTYPE, sdf_definition_key) 
               AND remittance_amount > 0
               AND (its_extnl_staging_document.submitted_dttm BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE)
        GROUP  BY sdf_definition_key 
        UNION 
        SELECT sdf_definition_key, 
               0        AS "Forms Filed with Payment", 
               Count(*) AS "Forms Filed without Payment",
               "submitted_dttm" AS submitted_dttm 
        FROM   its_extnl_staging_document 
        WHERE  sdf_definition_key = Isnull(@DOCTYPE, sdf_definition_key) 
               AND remittance_amount = 0
               AND (its_extnl_staging_document.submitted_dttm BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE)
        GROUP  BY sdf_definition_key
) its_extnl_staging_document 
LEFT JOIN r_sdf_definition 
       ON its_extnl_staging_document.sdf_definition_key = 
          r_sdf_definition.sdf_definition_key
WHERE its_extnl_staging_document.submitted_dttm BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
GROUP  BY r_sdf_definition.code
```

Comment: Are you talking about your very last WHERE clause?

Comment: You need to put the "its_extnl_staging_document.submitted_dttm BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE" on the two INNER selects.

Comment: 2nd example - change  `GROUP  BY sdf_definition_key` to  `GROUP  BY sdf_definition_key, submitted_dttm` and then you need to get max or min of submitted_dttm -- depending on your needs.

Comment: @JohnPasquet - you can't know that unless we see the requirements can we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the final WHERE clause, it actually is NOT present.

```
WHERE its_extnl_staging_document.submitted_dttm BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

The issue is that there is no column named "submitted_dttm" in your two select clauses that you have joined with UNION.

You need to either include it in each inner SELECT or put the WHERE clause in each SELECT.  You can leave the outer SELECT alone.

Another option is that the submitted_dttm column is on the other table with which you have LEFT JOINed.

UPDATE

This is a little different approach, but it might be easier to understand:

```
SELECT  sdf_definition_key, RemittanceType, COUNT(*)
FROM    its_extnl_staging_document
    LEFT JOIN r_sdf_definition 
        ON its_extnl_staging_document.sdf_definition_key = r_sdf_definition.sdf_definition_key
WHERE   sdf_definition_key = Isnull(@DOCTYPE, sdf_definition_key) 
GROUP BY r_sdf_definition.code,
    CASE    
        WHEN (remittance_amount = 0) THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END AS RemittanceType
```

This should give you two types of rows:

```
Key    RemittanceType    COUNT
```

You could wrap that in another select then.

Comment: So that makes perfect sense.  By adding this additional WHERE clause to the two inner selects, the query works as intended.  However, I want to point out that the last, outer select will still not work when I've added the where clauses to the inner statements.  I'll update my original post with this new observation.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes indents matter...

```
FROM   (SELECT sdf_definition_key,
               Count(*) AS "Forms Filed with Payment", 
               0        AS "Forms Filed without Payment",

               something AS submitted_dttm 

        FROM   its_extnl_staging_document 
        WHERE  sdf_definition_key = Isnull(@DOCTYPE, sdf_definition_key) 
               AND remittance_amount > 0 
        GROUP  BY sdf_definition_key 
        UNION 
        SELECT sdf_definition_key, 
               0        AS "Forms Filed with Payment", 
               Count(*) AS "Forms Filed without Payment",

               something AS submitted_dttm 


        FROM   its_extnl_staging_document 
        WHERE  sdf_definition_key = Isnull(@DOCTYPE, sdf_definition_key) 
               AND remittance_amount = 0 
        GROUP  BY sdf_definition_key
) its_extnl_staging_document 
LEFT JOIN r_sdf_definition 
       ON its_extnl_staging_document.sdf_definition_key = 
          r_sdf_definition.sdf_definition_key
WHERE its_extnl_staging_document.submitted_dttm BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

Comment: I used a SQL format tool online.  I'm not sure what you mean by indents matter, because the code you've re-posted has the same indentation as mine.

Comment: I've made the modifications you've suggested here and the new error is:  "Column 'its_extnl_staging_document.submitted_dttm' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Note, I do not wish to see the submitted date time in my result set

Comment: The formatting I have is totally different.  **LOOK AT WHERE THE WHERE CLAUSE YOU ARE ASKING ABOUT IS**.  ... Sorry I'm better now.  You are getting an error because I did not and CAN'T solve your problem unless you tell me all the requirements and make your data model 100% available.   I just showed you where to put the date information -- adding the group by, picking the correct field.  All of this you have to do because you have the knowledge that would allow you to do so.

Comment: The formatting is slightly different on the last two few lines.  Also I'm not following you on your point about the requirement.  I stated that the query worked before adding the where clause at the end.  Following your suggestion, which seems to be to add the aliased submitted_datetime to the inner selects, and then removing the outer group by, still causes the same problem.  I do not wish to select the date time into the aggregate result of the group by, I just wish to limit the select of the results by applying the where clause.  What John suggests above gets me there.  Thank you though.

Comment: @Matt1776 I did not say to remove any GROUP BY.   I'm glad you are happy, but I don't think you learned much.  Since it is possible that you will get different results from His solution and mine and understand the difference.  But as I said I can't know unless I know your full data model.

Comment: Actually, I did learn quite a bit when John pointed out I needed to limit the inner selects.  And I thought you intended me to remove the group by because your re-post of my selection did not include it.  This may have caused me to misunderstand you.